# How to enable Objectify XA transaction?

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, objectify

I'm implementing friendship functionality between entities of same type `Profile`. This entity kind is root (non parent) entity.
A Profile has a `Set<Ref<Profile>>` field named `friends` and it's getter `getFriends()`.

Here the code:

```
public boolean makeFriends(final Profile profile1, final Profile profile2) {
    final Ref<Profile> profileRef1 = Ref.create(profile1);
    final Ref<Profile> profileRef2 = Ref.create(profile2);

    boolean result = false;

    // test to avoid useless transaction
    if (!profile1.getFriends().contains(profileRef2) && !profile2.getFriends().contains(profileRef1)) {
        // add to friends (Set<Ref<Profile>>) the Ref of each other
        result = ofy().transact(new Work<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean run() {
                profile1.getFriends().add(profileRef2);
                profile2.getFriends().add(profileRef1);
                ofy().save().entities(profile1, profile2).now();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
    return result;
}
```

This code give me a:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified, see TransactionOptions.Builder.withXG
```

even if Objectify documentation says:

> Objectify requires no special flags to enable cross-group
>   transactions. If you access more than one entity group in a
>   transaction, the transaction with be an XG transaction. If you do
>   access only one, it is not. The standard limit of 5 EGs applies to all
>   transactions.

So, why my transaction fails?

My code should involve two entity groups (one for each `Profile`), so behind the limit of 5.
Looking at `TransactionOptions.Builder.withXG` documentation, i should call `TransactionOptions.Builder.withXG(true);` before.
This method returns a `TransactionOptions` but i don't know a method to pass it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: read this oracle community article:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312192/how-to-enable-xa-oracle-11g/30312193#30312193][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30312192/how-to-enable-xa-oracle-11g/30312193#30312193

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Objectify always turns on XG transactions if the environment supports it.

Most likely, you're running a test case without the HRD enabled. You must do this explicitly in your LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig; check the Local Unit Testing docs. If you are getting this message in the dev instance, make sure to check the "Use HRD" checkbox in the eclipse project preferences.

Comment: You're right, as usual. 
My current Test Case says 
`INFO: Local Datastore initialized: Type: Master/Slave Storage: In-memory`
if i change the configuration with
`LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig config = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(100);`
says
`INFO: Local Datastore initialized: Type: High Replication Storage: In-memory`
But all test fails :(

Comment: Solved with `LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig config = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setApplyAllHighRepJobPolicy();`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me but only after I add .setApplyAllHighRepJobPolicy to all my test classes that use datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Make  sure you activated the HRD in the local AppEngine for testing, using the VM flag:

```
-Ddatastore.default_high_rep_job_policy_unapplied_job_pct=1
```