# How to Enable XA Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, xa

We recently moved to Oracle 11g from MSSQL and am completely new to this. Can someone tell me how to enable XA transactions on Oracle? From what I gathered, I think I need to run initjvm.sql and initxa.sql but I am not entirely sure. Is there someway of doing this through the Enterprise manager? Also, what is the XA driver class called? Is that oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADatasource?

Answer (score 1):

Read this official Oracle Article:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/920935

And this:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/XA_FAQ

**Also**. You have to execute **$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/xaview.sql** as sysdba to have XA releated views created.

Perhaps, Metalink note : Required Grants For Retail Integration Bus Distributed XA Transaction-467466.1 Would help.